# Confusion about virtual displacement

Tags: classical-mechanics, definition, constrained-dynamics

From Goldstein:

> A virtual (infinitesimal) displacement of a system refers to a change in the configuration of the system as the result of any arbitrary infinitesimal change of the coordinates $\delta\mathbf{r}_i$, *consistent with the forces and constraints imposed on the system at the given instant $t$*.

From my *Mechanics* instructor (not verbatim):

> A virtual displacement is a displacement consistent with the system's constraints.

My instructor's definition of virtual displacement is crystal clear and Goldstein's isn't so I can't determine if they're compatible. What does Goldstein mean by "consistent with the forces"? I find this phrase to be extremely ambiguous. After clearing that up, please discuss the equivalence or lack thereof of these two statements.

Comment: Well it looks like your instructor's definition of contained within the book's definition.

Comment: More on [virtual displacement](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+virtual+displacement*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goldstein made a mistake. This is a screenshot from the [errata](http://astro.physics.sc.edu/goldstein/6-on.html).

[image: Error in Goldstein]